# How Do I get next state/event in Spring state Machine

Tags: spring-statemachine

1) I am processing a particular event from the transition, how Do I get the info about next event?
2) If I need to stop the transition from one state to another during the transition action, how Do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) I'm guessing your processing code runs in a transition's action.
You can get from the provided `StateContext` the source state, the target state, and the event that caused the transition.
You can't possibly get the next event, because it wasn't sent yet.

2) I don't think that's possible.
If the transition action might fail and it means that in this scenario you should go to an altogether different state - then you should redesign your statemachine to run this code from somewhere different than the transition action.
For example from the state's action, and send a different event based on success/failure.

Comment: Thanks for your response,
I ended up adding custom action and set some data in state context, and used transition guard to block or proceed with transaction.